# Multiple XCode 5 windows that have the same project open

Tags: xcode, multiple-monitors

I'm sitting here pulling my hair out trying to find a way to open the same project in two different XCode windows. Is there a way to do this? I want to be able to edit one file with another file on a separate monitor. So far everything I've tried just brings me back to the XCode I already have open.

Answer (score 3):

And two seconds later, I clicked File > New > Window. That did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also drag a tab out of the tab-bar and release the mouse. The tab will become a new window.

Comment: This doesn't work, or at least for me

Answer (score 1):

And to offer a third choice... double clicking does the job for me, too.